# Video in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i make the toggle fullscreen vídeo in html 5 and jquery/javascript ?

I try this, but dont work

```
<script>
$("#nomedogame8").click( function() {
var element = document.getElementById("nomedogame8");       
if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) 
{
element.mozRequestFullScreen();
} 
else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) 
{
element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
});
</script>


<script>
$("#nomedogame8").click( function() {
var element = document.getElementById("nomedogame8");     
if (element.mozCancelFullScreen)
{
element.mozCancelFullScreen();
}
else if (element.webkitExitFullscreen)
{
element.webkitExitFullscreen();
}
});
</script>
```

Hélp-me again please............................

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("nome");       
if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
element.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
```